# How to add character 's' on method that have class level @RequestMapping in spring-boot-web

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

Got class/interface level and method mapping

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/post")
 public interface PostApi {

    //to get /posts
    @RequestMapping(value = "s") 
    ResponseEntity getAll();
 }
```

Basically I want to add character 's' on /post and get /posts, how this is possible

Comment: Why dont you change your RequestMapping to `/posts`?  `@RequestMapping(value = "/posts")`

Comment: @pleft Because I want to use /post/{id} and not /posts/{id} , I dont like this /posts/{id} for specific post.. later on when adding more methods

Comment: The suggestion by @pleft is on the mark. It is a best practice to use plural nouns when referencing collections, see https://medium.com/@mwaysolutions/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api-cbe81b06f291 and https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface PostApi {

    //to get /posts
    @RequestMapping(value = "/posts") 
    ResponseEntity getAll();

    @GetMapping(value = "/post/{id}") 
    ResponseEntity getById(@PathParam Long id);
 }
```

Comment: There is no other way around it ? Is this the only way?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your example he is great but: is there a hack to add "post" +  "s" ? I'm looking for that solution if you understaind me ?

Comment: Ok understood but whats the reason for doing such a hack? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to have class level "/post" and on method to add "s".. Is this posible in Spring because I need to change others methods too to apply to this 'your answer', need to change to many methods

Comment: @acakojic There is no hack.  Use the plural in all cases or specify the path on a per-method basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the context path, instead remove "/post" then use below "/post" and "/posts" on different tasks.

Comment: There is no hack to add character 's' when using method to class level mapping without '/' between, that is stupid but ok..

Comment: That there is no hack is a good thing.  As you gain experience writing and using RESTful endpoints you will understand design decisions that seem "stupid" to you now.  One thing I can tell you with confidence is that the Spring Framework developers definitely know what they're doing.  Don't judge the API by your (inexperienced) expectations.

Comment: @Paul I just asking if there is hack for this because when other developers enter into my API and see class/interface level to know what they are looking if you understaind me, it is more readable then to mix into methods. I don't judge I'm just looking for solution if there is :-)))

Comment: @acakojic Other developers using your API and reading your code will expect `/posts` and not `/post`.

Answer (score 1):

you can not concatenate the path values into a single path string, since they are seen as objects in the URI specification and not multiple just strings.
(if you like RFCs, check this: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3 )

so basically your class-level Mapping already sets a hierarchy by design, and the method can only configure a lower level inside that hierarchy
((earlier) spring documentations featured this explanation:
"Method-level mappings are only allowed to narrow the mapping expressed at the class level (if any)."

the only way to work around this is actually to remove the class mapping and add individual mappings to either method (as stated by others).
as a side effect: this makes your code much better readable, so reviewers (or yourself in 3 months) do not have to concat the full path in your mind whily trying to understand the controller